# Computing Big O time complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

The time complexity of the following algorithm is reported to be O(v+e), but I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

This is the problem: In a weighted (nodes and edges) directed acyclic graph, an attribute, called Rank, is computed for every vertex. It is computed by traversing the graph bottom-up. For the exit node, the Rank value is assumed to be equal to its assigned weight. For any other node in the graph, the Rank is defined as:

"The Rank of the node's dominant successor" + "The wight of the edge between the node and its dominant successor" + "The node's weight"

where the node's dominant successor is the one with the highest Rank value.

This is what I guess the pseudocode of the algorithm is:

```
     For "every vertex" in the graph
        For "every immediate successor" of the selected vertex
           [the statements ...]
        End
     End
```

Choosing the nodes in the right topological order, the outer loop is executed exactly v times, resulting in O(v) time complexity.
The inner loop (Searching for successors) is executed at most (v-1) times (in case of using an adjacency matrix I guess), resulting in O(v) time complexity.
Therefore, I compute the total time complexity O(v^2), which is not correct according to the reported value which is O(v+e).

Comment: If you have an adjacency list, the inner loop iterates a total number of O(e) times because it essentially visits each edge once.

Comment: @NicoSchertler What if we were seeking the immediate predecessors of every node (for example in a similar problem in which Ranks are assigned by traversing the DAG upside-down)? As you suggested, using an adj list is the straight forward way of extracting every node's successors. But is it also usable in extracting the predecessors, or in this case we need to use an adj matrix, which takes v iterations to find each node's predecessors, resulting in O(v^2) total time complexity?

Comment: You can also store predecessors as an adjacency list.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an adjacency list instead of an adjacency matrix, it takes O(V + E). Because you're only visiting each node once (because you're keeping track of which nodes you visited), and also visiting every edge once (because you won't use an edge which has a visited node on the other end).

Here's some pseudocode-

```
queue<Node> q;
startNode = (starting node)
bool[numNodes] visited;
while (visited.size() < numNodes) {
    [check if visited]
    [mark as visited]
    [set rank]
    [add successors to the queue if they're not visited]
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that since the Rank of each node depends on the Ranks of its immediate successors (the Max function), nodes that are added to the queue at each step are the not visited ones whose immediate successors have been visited. So, every edge is visited once since extracting successors of a node is straight forward when the adj list is used. But would it be the same if in another problem the Rank was computed upside-down? Because, at each Rank-setting step, we needed to extract a node's predecessors. Is it doable using an adj list or in this case an adj matrix should be used?